# What's the proper Connection String format for deploying an Azure Function app through Azure Devops CI/CD?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I have several enviroments for an Azure Functions app, and releasing them through CI/CD and using the visual editor in Azure Devops>Releases. For each of those enviroments, I want to change the connection string, but a connection string has white spaces, and this happens:

Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {
"DbConnectionString":"Data",
"":"ID=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD"
}
##[error]Error: Failed to update App service 'FUNCTION_NAME' application settings. Error: BadRequest - Parameter name cannot be empty. (CODE: 400)

This is my configuration in the Release Pipeline, same for every Task.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Uho.png)

What am I missing, or what's the proper format?

I tried to surround the variable in " " but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding app setting as Connection string  with space in my Azure Function release pipeline as variables and it was successful:-

I added the Release pipeline variable like below:-

**My app setting:-**

```
ConnectionStrings.MyDatabase Server=tcp:dev.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Employess
```

[image]

In my Release pipeline referenced the above variable like below:-

```
-ConnectionStrings.MyDatabase "$(ConnectionStrings.MyDatabase)"
```

[image]

***Ran the release pipeline and got the desired output:-***

[image]

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But your white space is at the end of the string, and it doesn't show. So we don't really know if it worked...

Comment: @Daniel The entire string was visible in the App setting including the white space in my Function app the above image is just a half string if I open that setting, I see the entire connection string.  Did you have Any luck with the same steps as I did above?